# Transform an array without using `transpose`

Tags: arrays, ruby

Looking for a way to take the `swingers` array below and swap all the partners while keeping male/female pairs. What I find confusing is how to iterate over two dimensional arrays

> Implement a Swingers game. The method swingers should take an array
>   of couple arrays and return the same type of data structure, with the 
>   couples mixed up. Assume that the first item in the couple array is a
>   man, and the second item is a woman. Don't pair a person with someone
>   of their own gender (sorry to ruin your fun). An example run of the
>   program:

```
swingers([
  ["Clyde", "Bonnie"],
  ["Paris", "Helen"],
  ["Romeo", "Juliet"]
])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking for help debugging code, we expect you to provide us the input data, your expected output, and the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having with it, along with a very good explanation of what you're trying to do and why you think it's not working. As is, it looks like homework, and that you haven't done anything to solve it and want us to write the code for you. If so, how do you expect to learn?

Comment: Now _that's_ computer science!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you don't need to use `transpose` at all:

```
def swingers(pairs)
  gents = pairs.map(&:first)
  ladies = pairs.map(&:last)
  gents.shuffle.zip(ladies.shuffle)
end
```

Comment: If swapping the partners is the only purpose, then I think you only need to do `shuffle` to one gender.

Comment: @sawa I agree, but, then the list won't look very randomised. So the second shuffle is for...cosmetic appeal. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what "couples mixed up" means. I suspect that if Bob and Zelda came to the party together, they probably would not be paired with each other. (I'm just going on what I've heard about swingers' parties). Let's say "couples" attend the party and a "valid pairing" is one where no pairing is a couple.

```
couples = [
  ["Clyde", "Bonnie"],
  ["Paris", "Helen"],
  ["Romeo", "Juliet"]
]
```

**Without randomization**

The word "random" does not appear in the problem description, so any  valid pairing may be acceptable. If that's the case, here's one way you could do that:

```
couples.map(&:first).zip(couples.map(&:last).rotate 1)
  #=> [["Clyde", "Helen"], ["Paris", "Juliet"], ["Romeo", "Bonnie"]]
```

**With randomization**

If randomization is required, here's a way to obtain a valid random pairing:

```
def pair_em(couples)
  h = Hash[couples]
  gents, ladies = h.keys.shuffle, h.values.shuffle 
  a = gents.map { |g| [g, (h[g]==ladies.first) ? ladies.pop : ladies.shift] }
  # Swap last two gents' ladies if last pairing was a couple
  (a[-2][-1], a[-1][-1] = a[-1][-1], a[-2][-1]) if h[a[-1].first] == a[-1].last
  a
end

10.times { p pair_em(couples) }
[["Paris", "Bonnie"], ["Clyde", "Juliet"], ["Romeo",  "Helen"]]
[["Romeo",  "Helen"], ["Paris", "Bonnie"], ["Clyde", "Juliet"]]
[["Romeo",  "Helen"], ["Paris", "Bonnie"], ["Clyde", "Juliet"]]
[["Romeo", "Bonnie"], ["Clyde",  "Helen"], ["Paris", "Juliet"]]
[["Clyde", "Juliet"], ["Romeo",  "Helen"], ["Paris", "Bonnie"]]
[["Paris", "Bonnie"], ["Romeo",  "Helen"], ["Clyde", "Juliet"]]
[["Paris", "Bonnie"], ["Clyde", "Juliet"], ["Romeo",  "Helen"]]
[["Romeo",  "Helen"], ["Clyde", "Juliet"], ["Paris", "Bonnie"]]
[["Paris", "Juliet"], ["Romeo", "Bonnie"], ["Clyde",  "Helen"]]
[["Clyde", "Juliet"], ["Romeo",  "Helen"], ["Paris", "Bonnie"]]
```

Is it necessary to shuffle both the gents and ladies (as I've done) to ensure that the randomization is unbiased? I don't think so, but I'm not sure about that.

Alternatively, one could simply loop using @Chris' solution until a valid pairing is obtained.